# does IIS Logs only contain the incoming requests?

Tags: iis, logging

does IIS Logs only contain the incoming requests?

If yes, then is there a way to log the outgoing requests as well.

Comment: What do you mean by outgoing requests? It certainly logs some details about the *response* to the incoming requests, but not any other arbitrary code that ran during request processing.

Comment: If your web apps send out requests to other places, it is your responsibilities to add application level logging to capture them.

Comment: @LexLi thanks, this the answer what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copied from the comment.

IIS log files are designed to only log incoming requests/responses IIS handled.

If your web apps send requests to other machines, IIS won't log them in its own log files. Instead, you need to do application level logging.